# User Login credentials and MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, collections, login-control

I am developing an email campaign application in PHP and using MongoDB to store user campaigns. I need suggestions to store my users profile and login credentials so that I can relate each user with his created campaigns.

As of now I am just saving all campaigns as mongo documents in campaigns collection. Now I want to make the users login first and then save user id with each campaign they create.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show what you are doing, and what sort of access to the information you require in your question. Otherwise it sounds like you are asking for suggestions in general, and as such is off-topic as that will only be opinions in general.

Comment: I am developing an email campaign application where users can create campaigns and sends to their contacts. I am using the mongodb for storing the campaigns. Now I need to register and login users and then associate campaigns with each user who has created it. I have nothing live yet.

Comment: My Question is similar to this http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20103/store-user-passwords-in-nosql-database